# Why is the stub only being used in the first test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got an rspec test that stubs an S3 client.  I can successfully stub a method on this client (say method A), in the second test, I want to stub a different method (say method B).  However, the second test never uses the stub.  If I switch the order of the tests, the second one never uses the stubbed method regardless of it's functionality (say I test B before A, B will pass and A will fail).  What gives?

```
require 'spec_helper'


describe ANY_S3_ACCESSOR_CLASS do

  before(:each) do
    @bucket = 'any_bucket'
    @key = 'any_key'
    @s3_double = Aws::S3::Client.new(stub_responses: true)
    Aws::S3::Client.stub(:new).with(anything).and_return(@s3_double)
  end

  context "getting an S3 document" do
    it "should get an S3 document successfully" do
      expected_get_output = 'any_output'
      @s3_double.stub(:get_object).with(anything).and_return(expected_get_output)
      returned_document = NY_S3_ACCESSOR.instance.get_document(@bucket, @key)

      expect(returned_document).to eq(expected_get_output)
    end
  end

  context "putting an S3 document" do
    it "should put a file saved locally to disk to S3 successfully" do
      expected_put_output = 'any_put_output'
      csv_file = CSV.open("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/any_well_formed_csv.csv")
      @s3_double.stub(:put_object).with(anything).and_return(expected_put_output)
      actual_put_output = NY_S3_ACCESSOR.instance.write_local_file(@bucket, @key, csv_file.path)

      expect(actual_put_output).to eq(expected_put_output)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post little code so other will not imagine code

Comment: done, note that I've had to rename certain things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the class under test was a singleton.  I followed the guidance found here ([Resetting a singleton instance in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127336/resetting-a-singleton-instance-in-ruby)) to unit test a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

```
@s3_double = Aws::S3::Client.new(stub_responses: true)
Aws::S3::Client.stub(:new).with(anything).and_return(@s3_double)
```

Aren't those lines reversed?  In any case, it seems likely that @s3_double is not always what you expect.  I would debug the hell out of that for the success and fail case and see what it looks like.

Comment: It was because the class under test was a singleton.  I followed the guidance found here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127336/resetting-a-singleton-instance-in-ruby) to unit test a singleton.